# PDO ODBC return null for a column value but odbc_conect doesn't

Tags: php, sql, pdo, hana, unixodbc

For some weird reason, my PDO keeps returning NULL when it should return a string/integer. I've tried to use the `odbc_conect` and it works fine.

Context:

- CentOS 7
- PHP 7.1.13
- unixODBC 2.3.1 (x86_64 . 11.el7)
- ODCB Driver: SAP HANA ODBC v2.2.36.1512099132 64 bits

When it's happening? Until now, I detected few:

- Function returns:   `SELECT id,GEO.ST_Asgeojson()  FROM DEV.GEOMETRIES`
- Using CAST: `SELECT  id, CAST(GEO.ST_AsText() AS VARCHAR) FROM DEV.GEOMETRIES` or `SELECT   CAST(1 AS INTEGER)  AS  "int"  FROM  DUMMY`
- Any blob column : `SELECT id,GEO FROM DEV.GEOMETRIES`
- Date Types: `SELECT insertdate FROM DEV.GEOMETRIES`

I also tried to use [PDOStatement::bindColumn](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindcolumn.php) to force data types but was unsuccessful

Where the code :

```
<?php
try{
    ini_set('memory_limit','256M'); //odbc_fetch_array is hungry
    // $sql = 'SELECT  NOW()  AS  "now"  FROM  DUMMY';
     $sql = "SELECT id,GEO.ST_Asgeojson(),GEO.ST_AsText(),insertdate  FROM DEV.geometries limit 1";
     //$sql = "SELECT *  FROM DEV.geometries limit 1";
    // $sql = "SELECT  CAST(GEO.ST_AsText() AS VARCHAR) from geometries";
    // $sql = "SELECT  CAST(10 AS VARCHAR) from DUMMY";
    // $sql = "SELECT  CAST(10 AS INTEGER) from DUMMY";

    echo "SQL: ",$sql,PHP_EOL;

    $DSN = "DRIVER=HANADB;UID=DEV;PWD=DEV@pwd;SERVERNODE=192.168.1.163:39013;DATABASENAME=SYSTEMDB";
    $options = [
        \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        \PDO::ATTR_CASE =>\PDO::CASE_LOWER, //Compatibility with mysql case
        \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true //With or without 
    ];
    echo "############# Using PDO:ODBC:",PHP_EOL;
    $DB =  new \PDO("odbc:".$DSN,'DEV','DEV@pwd',$options);

    echo "Driver: ",$DB->getAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_CLIENT_VERSION),PHP_EOL;
        echo "Using Prepared Statement:",PHP_EOL;


    $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
    // bindColumn Also doesn't work
    //$stmt->bindColumn('id', $id, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
    //$stmt->bindColumn('geojson', $geometry, \PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    $stmt->execute();

    /*while ($row = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_BOUND)) {
         var_dump($row);
         var_dump($id, $geometry);
     }*/


    //var_dump($ret,$stmt);
    var_export($stmt->fetchAll());

    $stmt->closeCursor();
    echo PHP_EOL,"Using Query:",PHP_EOL;
    $qR = $DB->query($sql);
    foreach($qR as $row){
        var_export($row);
    }
    echo PHP_EOL,PHP_EOL,"#############  Using odbc_*( ) Functions",PHP_EOL;
    $conn = odbc_connect($DSN,'DEV','DEV@pwd');
    $rs = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
      while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs)){
          var_export($row);
      } 
}catch(\Exception $e){  
    echo $e->getMessage(),PHP_EOL,$e->getTraceAsString();
}
```

Output:

```
############# Using PDO:ODBC:
Using Prepared Statement:
array (
  0 =>
  array (
    'id' => '363491',
    'geojson' => NULL,
    'geotext' => NULL,
    '__dateinsert' => NULL,
    'info' => NULL,
  ),
)
Using Query:
array (
  'id' => '363491',
  'geojson' => NULL,
  'geotext' => NULL,
  'insertdate' => NULL,
  'info' => NULL,
)

#############  Using odbc_*( ) Functions
array (
  'id' => '363491',
  'geojson' => '{"type": "Point", "coordinates": [16.352878, 48.225628]}',
  'geotext' => 'POINT (16.352878 48.225628)',
  'insertdate  ' => '2018-02-06 15:08:19.414000000',
  'info' => NULL,
)
```

I'm not sure if it's a Drive problem because it works with `odbc_*` functions, maybe it's a PDO BUG.

Comment: Where does the `array(3) { ... }` in the output come from?

Comment: It was a dump from `PDOStatement::errorInfo`, I removed it thanks.

Comment: It does look to me like it could be a bug but don't have an ODBC server to test on. Have you tried one of the other [drivers](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php)? Also, does this error occur for all column types, or just specific ones? If so, which?

Comment: @Mike It's very weird,  I have thought that happens for a blob or "special" types but happens for INT and CHARs too, the left side shows an odbc_* result on the right the PDO fetch.
https://www.diffchecker.com/MsJQq1Z5

Comment: Have you tried another driver?

Comment: I just tested another version from the same drive, I don't know if have other driver to connect into SAP Hana

Comment: That driver isn't even listed in the PHP docs page (http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php). It could very well be a problem with the driver, but I literally have zero experience with ODBC, so I could be talking about something completely different. I'm not sure what type of Unix you're using, but if it's Debian (or derivatives), it might be as easy as installing the `php-odbc` package.

Comment: @Mike the drive is ODBC, connecting using PDO_ODBC for generic ODBC drivers. 
The context about Unix, versions and more information is described in the question. Thanks for your effort to try help.

Comment: same issue happened with PHP_ODBC + vertica and doesnt konw how to fix it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57820264/6266737